# How to load mesh in new thread

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I am making my first game and I am stuck with one problem. I have a world where you can walk free, but then when you meet the enemy you will switch to battle and when you are switching to battle, I need to load all the models that will be rendered in the battle scene. The loading takes about ~5 seconds and I want to make the loading screen. So, I rendered the loading screen in the main thread, but how can I load 3d models and build different VAO and VBO at the same time? I made a new thread for this loading, but I read online "don't use threads for generating VAOs". What is the best solution to make this loading? Should I just preload all the models in the main thread before the game starts? Personally, for me it seems not right to load all the 3d models in the beginning of the game.

Comment: "don't use threads for generating VAOs" - it depends, from where do you have that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have two windows, you can bind each context of the window to separate threads. Problems will arise if you share data between them (proper locking is mandatory).

See [glfwMakeContextCurrent](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__context.html#ga1c04dc242268f827290fe40aa1c91157):

> This function makes the OpenGL or OpenGL ES context of the specified window current on the calling thread. A context must only be made current on a single thread at a time and each thread can have only a single current context at a time.
>
> **Thread safety**:
> This function may be called from any thread.

See [glfwSwapBuffers](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga15a5a1ee5b3c2ca6b15ca209a12efd14):

> This function swaps the front and back buffers of the specified window when rendering with OpenGL or OpenGL ES.
>
> **Thread safety**:
> This function may be called from any thread.

Some functions in GLFW can only be called from the 'main' thread (nor from callbacks), e.g. [glfwPollEvents](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga37bd57223967b4211d60ca1a0bf3c832), but other than that, bind the context to a thread, perform your OpenGl calls and swap the buffers. As said before, as long as you don't share any buffers, there should be no problem.